# TYPO3: category tree of tx-news, render sub-tree only if main is selected

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I override `Templates/Styles/TWB/Templates/Category/List.html` to have the category menu behave exactly as the sidebar menu in the introduction package (submenus show only if main is selected).

If I add the static template "News Styles Twitter Bootstrap (news)" I'm almost there, it is not difficult to open the sub-categories only if the main category is selected (I need a massive amount of categories/sub-categories), but it should also be open when a sub is selected:

```
...
    <f:if condition="{0:category.item.uid,1:category.item.uid} == {0:overwriteDemand.categories,1:category.children.{overwriteDemand.categories}.parent}">
        <f:if condition="{category.children}">
            <f:render section="categoryTree" arguments="{categories: category.children,overwriteDemand:overwriteDemand,class:''}" />
        </f:if>
    </f:if>
...
```

I do not know how to use `{overwriteDemand.categories}` as key to match the value ... can anybody point to the proper syntax

**update**: I tried to apply a custom ViewHelper as [this post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731150/typo3-fluid-complex-if-conditions/19740983#19740983), but using TYPO3 V7.6.16 got stuck with the error `should be compatible with TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper:‌​:render()`, so could not try working with the variable `overwriteDemand.categories` in another way ...

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic access to variables in fluid is just possible since TYPO3 8. Check out the Whats New Slides here: https://typo3.org/download/release-notes/whats-new/ and search for "Dynamic variable name parts" in the PDF.

In TYPO3 7, the "vhs"-Extension provides [a ViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Variable/GetViewHelper.html) to do the same job but nesting a ViewHelper within an complex f:if-condition is even more difficult. If possible, try out TYPO3 8. If it's not possible you may write your own ViewHelper to solve this logical problem.

Comment: Hi paul, The whole site is ready now but I still did not work out this problem, V8 is not an option, but with my own viewhelper I get stuck ... can you give me a pointer ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731150/typo3-fluid-complex-if-conditions looked fine but gives errors ...